# Duplicate spring properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have two spring properties files, one that used by the integration tests and one that is used for the actual project. The properties files are mostly the  same but in the test properties file I have a couple of properties that are different for test purposes. This is a maintenance pain, every time I add a property I have to copy it into the test properties file even if it exactly the same. I just had a bug in the tests that was caused because the test properties file hadn't been updated.

I have a `application-context-test.xml` that imports a lot of the beans from the project `application-context.xml`, but overrides the beans it needs to for test purposes, can I do the same for the properties files?

Here are my property file configurations

`application-context.xml`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:myproject.properties"/>
</bean>
```

`application-context-test.xml`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:myproject-test.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two files with different properties and load both of them like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
            <list>
               <value="classpath:myproject-test.properties"/>
               <value="classpath:myproject.properties"/>
            </list>
     </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Will the properties in myproject-test.properties override the same properties in myproject.properties?

Comment: Default behavior of loading properties in java overrides the old values if same property is loaded again. So it should also do the same. try reversing the order of property files to get desired behavior.